# React Router DOM doesn't catch errors

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build a small app that uses simple routing, and everything seems to work fine, except for error handling. Firsly, React Router DOM (RRD) doesn't do anything about non-existent paths. As far as I know, it should show some generic error message. Secondly, it doesn't catch errors thrown inside Route components.

All I have tried so far, is that I've updated RRD to the latest version. Previously it was v6.9.0 and now it is v6.11.0

App.ts

```
import Main from './modules/main/main';
import ErrorPage from './modules/error/error-page';
import Entry from './modules/entry/entry';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppSelector } from './store/hooks';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const { loggedUserId } = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          errorElement={<ErrorPage />}
          element={loggedUserId ? <Main /> : <Navigate to="/entry" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/entry"
          errorElement={<ErrorPage />}
          element={!loggedUserId ? <Entry /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Not positive, but I wonder if you need `useRouteError` (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)

Comment: I've never used `errorElement` so can't tell about your second part of the question, however for the "*..about non-existent paths*" you could use a `Route` with `path="*"` and an `element` for "PageNotFound" at the very bottom, yours `errorElement` also seems repetitive

Comment: The `Route` component's `errorElement` prop is a data router-only prop, it won't work in regular router components.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, problem gone. All that time I had been using BrowserRouter for routing stuff, which is a no-fit for this kind of error-catching functionality. Should've used 'createBrowserRouter', that really does the trick.

Comment: Thank you! 
I came across this problem just now and have no idea what went wrong. Now that you mentioned about the type of router, I just realized it actually written on the official page: 
> This feature only works if using a data router, see [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)
Oh, silly me